# Moving files within amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have uploaded files on s3 bucket. 
But due to my fault, s3cmd uploaded files on s3://backups/files/bkup14 instead of s3://backups/bkup14.
Now for moving all the files under s3://backups/files/bkup14 to s3://backups/bkup14, I tried below command:

`s3cmd mv --recursive s3://backups/files/bkup14 s3://backups/bkup14`

But it gives me below error:

```
ERROR: S3 error: 400 (InvalidRequest): This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption attributes.
```

What I am doing wrong here? Can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

Try SYNC the buckets first (alway dry-run first):

```
s3cmd sync s3://backups/files/bkup14/ s3://backups/bkup14/ --dry-run
s3cmd sync s3://backups/files/bkup14/ s3://backups/bkup14/
```

then delete the folder that you no longer require:

```
s3cmd del --recursive s3://backups/files/bkup14 --dry-run
s3cmd del --recursive s3://backups/files/bkup14
```

AWS S3 bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system, so unless you're extremely lucky to catch the **backups** bucket your s# bucket is most probably something else.

Below is a example of the above tested and proved.

```
s3cmd sync s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/ s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/bkup14/ --dry-run
  Summary: 1 source files to copy, 0 files at destination to delete
  Sync: s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/test.txt -> s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/bkup14/test.txt
  WARNING: Exitting now because of --dry-run

s3cmd sync s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/ s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/bkup14/
  Summary: 1 source files to copy, 0 files at destination to delete
  File s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/test.txt copied to s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/bkup14/test.txt
  Done. Copied 1 files in 0.1 seconds, 16.72 files/s

s3cmd del --recursive s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14 --dry-run
  delete: s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/
  delete: s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/test.txt
  WARNING: Exitting now because of --dry-run

s3cmd del --recursive s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14
  File s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/ deleted
  File s3://backups-stackoverflow-demo/files/bkup14/test.txt deleted
```

Comment: I tried to sync buckets using your command but I got error: Parameter problem: Invalid source/destination

Comment: I hope you didn't copy the commands verbatim and substituted the bucket name "backup" with you real bucket.

What is the output of **s3cmd ls**?